# Modify values of a numpy array based on a condition

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I have a numpy array as follows:

```
list_of_values = [-0.5, -0.8, -0.6, -0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, -0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0, -0.3, -0.2, 0, -0.6, 0, 0.3]
array= np.array(list_of_values)
```

I need an array of the same size, having a 1 when the value goes from negative to positive, and a -1 when the value goes from positive to negative, and a 0 for the rest. If there is a 0 in list_of_values, and it bounces back, it should not be considered as the 0 line has been crossed.

This is the exact output that I am looking for

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

The real list_of_values is large, with 3000+ numbers, so the solution should use Numpy (some for loop is not valid), and it should be quick.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.ediff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 1, -0.3, 0.2, 0.6])
>>> np.ediff1d(np.sign(arr), to_begin=0) // 2
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.])
```

If you'd like to consider `0` as positive:

```
>>> arr = np.array([-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.1, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 1, -0.3, 0.2, 0.6])
>>> np.ediff1d(np.where(arr==0, 1, np.sign(arr)), to_begin=0)//2
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.])
```

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, you can do the following:

```
>>> arr = [-0.5, -0.8, -0.6, -0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, -0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0, -0.3, -0.2, 0, -0.6, 0, 0.3]
>>> output = np.array(arr)
>>> nonzero_idx = output != 0
>>> nonzero_arr = output[nonzero_idx]
>>> res = np.ediff1d(np.sign(nonzero_arr), to_begin=0) // 2
>>> output[nonzero_idx] = res
>>> output
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really appreciate it. What if I wanted to treat 0 as indifferent, meaning that if [..., +, 0, +, ...], the third value would not be -1, and the other way around, if [..., -, 0, -, ....], the third value would not be +1

Comment: Well actually I didn't know what you wanted in case of `0`. Could you add an input with 0 and expected output in your question? I can update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Cyttorak is correct and a lot prettier than mine, however, if you don't mind a little bit uglier code and want speed, this is faster.

```
a2 = np.array([-1, 1])
array = np.array([-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 1, -0.3, 0.2, 0.6])
array = np.where(array >= 0, -1, 1)
output = np.convolve(array, a2, mode='same')
output = np.where((output == 2) | (output == -2), output, 0) // 2
```

Edit: sorry, forgot to copy-paste a2 :D